# my java program skip steps

Tags: java, math, skip

So my program works fine until the end where it has to calculate and then show the results.It just show the result without calculating the "if" at the end.

```
 public class Convertisseur1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String valeurInitial;
    String valeurPoid;
    String valeurDesire;
    String valeurInitial2;
    String valeurInitial3;

    //seperation des string
    valeurInitial = (args[0]);
    valeurInitial2 = (args[0]);
    valeurDesire = (args[1]);
    valeurInitial3 = (args[0]);

    valeurInitial = valeurInitial.replace("kg",""); 
    valeurInitial = valeurInitial.replace("g","");      
    valeurInitial = valeurInitial.replace("t","");      
    valeurInitial = valeurInitial.replace("lb","");     
    double valeurdouble = Double.parseDouble(valeurInitial);

    valeurInitial2 = valeurInitial2.substring(valeurInitial2.length()-2);
    valeurInitial3 = valeurInitial3.substring(valeurInitial3.length()-1);       
    //convertion    
    System.out.println(valeurInitial2);
    System.out.println(valeurDesire);
    System.out.println(valeurdouble);
    if(valeurInitial2 == "kg" &&valeurDesire == "g"){
        valeurdouble = (valeurdouble*1000); 
        System.out.println("La convertion finale : " + valeurdouble);
    }else if(valeurInitial2 == "kg"&&valeurDesire == "lb")
        valeurdouble = (valeurdouble/2.2046226);

    /*System.out.println(valeurdouble);
    //System.out.println(valeurPoid);
    System.out.println(valeurDesire);
    System.out.println(valeurInitial2);
    System.out.println(valeurInitial3);*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as yet another String comparison question.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the {} on the else if and It doesn't print anything at the last if because it needs another System.out.println() as it isn't a loop.

```
}else if(valeurInitial2.equals( "kg" ) && valeurDesire.equals("lb" ) ){
    valeurdouble = (valeurdouble/2.2046226);
    System.out.println("La convertion finale : " + valeurdouble);
}
```

Comment: ty for the answer but the program still skips the calculation here is what i get on cmd when i enter 8kg g        cmd:   kg g 8.0 then it end

Comment: Well, I see you use "==" to compare strings, in java you need to use .equals function to compare strings.

Comment: if(valeurInitial2.equals( "kg" ) && valeurDesire.equals( "g" )){ //stuff }

Comment: it works thanks alot Ramiro!